# Laravel Many to Many Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have a `products` table and a `categories` table and a `pivot` table.

**Product** (`products`)

-- id

-- name

**Category** (`categories`)

-- id

-- name

**CategoryProduct** (`category_product`)

-- category_id

-- product_id

I want to get all products that belong to a certain category, I have managed to get it by doing the following query:

```
$products = Category::find(3)->products;
```

But how can I access it off the product model?

```
$products = Product::?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `whereHas` clause. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('id', 3);
})->get();
```

Or you can do it with a join instead.

```
$products = Product::select('products.*')
    ->join('category_product', 'products.id', '=', 'category_product.product_id')
    ->where('category_product.category_id', 3)
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous.

That is the error I get when I run your code

Comment: Which snippet gives that error? Did you add any other clauses, scopes, etc?

Comment: The first snippet.

Comment: @robertmylne What edit did you make? What was the problem?

Comment: The edit got rejected for some reason by @pang. This return $query->where('id', 3); changed to this return $query->where('category_id', 3); removes the error

Comment: Is the auto-increment key for your `categories` table not `id`?

Comment: Okay. I can't see why the aforementioned snippet should give you that error.